# Flutter: fullscreen background image covered by bottomnavigationbar

Tags: flutter

Using the following Flutter code (v.1.22.5), I am struggling with the issue that the background image won't be displayed fullscreen (currently in Android 11, haven't tested it for iOS yet), as it is covered by the white section at the very bottom of the screen. How can I make the highlighted white bar at the bottom disappear/transparent - or what else has to be done - so that the background image can be perceived truly fullscreen? I've tried several approaches but nothing helped.

[image]

My code:

```
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent, // navigation bar color

      systemNavigationBarDividerColor:
          Colors.transparent, //Navigation bar divider color
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this in your initState to hide the status and navigation bar.

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

But If you want to hide only the bottom navigation bar, then try calling this on your initState.

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Comment: Using this instruction, the bottom white bar disappears but now the status bar turns black and I have a black bar covering the background image at the top end XD

Comment: Damn, my mistake. You are perfectly right: using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]); only the bottom bar disappears. Thanks for that.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to apply this setting for launch screen too, as I am experiencing a black bar at the bottom of the screen as well which covers the background image while the app starts up.